# Strange derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

In this proof:

http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/mean_value/proof_mean.html

[image]

Why does $g'(x) = f'(x) - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$?

Comment: The question would be better received if you included all the context in the question, rather than provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

The linked proof defines

$$g(x) = f(x) - \left[\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}(x - a) + f(a)\right]$$

Rewrite this slightly as

$$g(x) = f(x) - \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} x - \left[\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}(-a) + f(a)\right] = f(x) - c x - d$$

where $c$ and $d$ are constant with respect to $x$. Recall that the derivative of a constant is zero, and the derivative of $cx$ is $c$; thus,

$$g'(x) = f'(x) - c - 0 = f'(x) - c$$

Comment: Thanks, but why do you write $cf(x)$ ? When was $f(x)$ defined as $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$?

Comment: @user3200098 $f$ isn't defined that way; I define $c = (f(b) - f(a))/(b - a)$; it's a messy constant, but it's still a constant.

Comment: I totally understand your explanation but I'm just wondering why it's $c \cdot f(x)$ I would have written $c \cdot x$.

Comment: @user3200098 Because of typos.... My apologies.

Comment: Ok. Since you provided such a great explanation, could you do me a huge favor and tell me why $g(a)=g(b)=0$? It doesn't seem obvious to me. I'm having problems understanding where the $y$ went and why there's an $f(x)$ all of a sudden instead in this $g(x)$.

Comment: @user3200098 Just plug $x = a$ into the definition of $g(x)$; you should find that $$g(a) = f(a) - \left[\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}(a - a) + f(a)\right] = f(a) - \left[0 + f(a)\right] =  0$$ and likewise for $b$.